# QR code with logo cannot be recognized by my app's QR code scanner

Tags: android, kotlin, qr-code

I have created an app with QR code scanner, however I can't scan a QR code with a logo using it, any solution for this?

This is the code of my QR code scanner app:

```
class QRCode (val onQrCodeScanned: (String) -> Unit) : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private val supportedImageFormats = listOf(
        ImageFormat.YUV_420_888 ,
        ImageFormat.YUV_422_888 ,
        ImageFormat.YUV_444_888)

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
    if (image.format in supportedImageFormats) {
        val bytes = image.planes.first().buffer.toByteArray()

        val source = PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(
                bytes,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                0,
                0,
                image.width,
                image.height,
                false)
        val binaryBmp = BinaryBitmap(HybridBinarizer(source))
        try {
            val result = MultiFormatReader().apply {
                setHints(
                        mapOf(
                                DecodeHintType.POSSIBLE_FORMATS to arrayListOf(
                                        BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE
                                                                              )
                             )
                        )
            }.decode(binaryBmp)
            onQrCodeScanned(result.text)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            image.close()
        }
    }
}

private fun ByteBuffer.toByteArray(): ByteArray {
    rewind()
    return ByteArray(remaining()).also {
        get(it)
    }
}

}
```

It can scan other QR codes but not QR codes with logo.

This is my QR code:
[image]

Comment: @blackapps already added it.

Comment: Although you've fixed your problem, but I had developed a highly advanced QR app once and I'd suggest you should switch to Google Mobile Vision from Zxing, Google's one performs way better.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it... The problem is in-app browsers cannot process websites that are built using Javascript.

This is what my code for launching the browser looks like before and after:

Before:

```
@Composable
fun LoadWebUrl(url: String) {
val context = LocalContext.current
AndroidView(factory = {
    WebView(context).apply {
        webViewClient = WebViewClient()
        loadUrl(url)
    }
})
}
```

After:

```
@Composable
fun LoadWebUrl(url: String) {
val context = LocalContext.current
IntentUtils.launchBrowser(context, url)
}
```

Comment: ????? What has launching a website to do with decoding a qr-code?

Comment: @blackapps the QR code contains a link to the URL of a web page that I have created using javascript. I think in-app browser of android apps doesn't have a support for those kind of websites that's why it's not loading it.